# How to list files in directory based on order in column

Tags: terminal, shutil, listdir

I have files listed in a non-alphabetical order in a column in my csv. I want to list the files in the directory according to the order of the csv. I made a .txt file of all the file names (plus extensions) in the order I want them in. How do I reorder files in the directory based on the order of files in the txt file?